# Google Calendar api oath2 request via PHP returns an empty string instead of authorization code

Tags: google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

Trying to get past the first step of Google Calendar API's authorization process: Obtaining an authorization code.  I'm able to get results by running the following URL in a browser:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
&response_type=code
&client_id=[ClientId]
&redirect_uri=[CallbackUri]
```

Google redirects to a page asking for *permission to access the requested Calendar*.  Once that permission is granted, it follows the redirect and provides the code.  That code works fine.

If I try to do the same via CURL command, via POST or GET, I get an empty string (see snippets below).  Perhaps what's needed is some extra bit of info, either an additional bit of data or a header, maybe a permission on the Google Developer side, that's the equivalent of the permission page encountered when doing this via browser.

Curiously, the next step in the process, getting the Access Token, functions perfectly using CURL.

Code Snippets:
Here's the GET version

```html
$Url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
$Url.="scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";
$Url.="&redirect_uri=http://localhost";
$Url.="&response_type=code";
$Url.="&client_id=[ClientId]";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Here's the POST version

```html
$Url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
$PostData=array(
 "scope"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
 "redirect_uri"=>"http://localhost",
 "response_type"=>"code",
 "client_id"=>"[ClientId]"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Try the [Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview), it might help you on how calendar api works (authorization, getting events, insert events etc.). "You can use this REST API by making explicit HTTP calls, but it's almost always easier to use the client library for your language of choice." Also you could try enabling the developer tool to check if anything happens during the request. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rebot. One of the goals here was to avoid the library, and it, harder or easier, it should be nonetheless possible to at least get a authorization code form a curl call.  Following your suggestions, I did make some progress.  Posting above.